# Cratonization - how did the Archean cratons form?

Tags: geophysics, plate-tectonics, models, earth-history

Before the onset of modern style plate tectonics and the Wilson cycles in the [late Archean](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-33823-y), it is thought that smaller units of continental crust, called [cratons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craton), roamed the oceanic crust over a more vigorously convecting mantle. These cratons already show [structures](https://pubs.geoscienceworld.org/gsa/lithosphere/article/6/1/35/145696/Craton-formation-Internal-structure-inherited-from) that suggest that they collided and accreted back in the day. Also, it is assumed that by the end of the Archean, 70% of today's crust had already been formed, though probably not at greater depths, and with a [significant change](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0016703719305009) around the time tectonics kicked in.

The Wikipedia article suggests 3 formation processes, but the cite link is broken.

> 1) surface crust was thickened by a rising plume of deep molten material, 2) successive subducting plates of oceanic lithosphere became lodged beneath a proto-craton in an under-plating process, 3) accretion from island arcs or continental fragments rafting together to thicken into a craton

My questions would be: Would uplift by a rising plume or underplating lift the originally basaltic material high enough for erosion to kick in and produce felsic/silicate/continental sediments, pre 2.5Gy ? Was the basement already solid enough to support the weight of mountains ? If i am not mistaken, todays exposed metamorphic old shields underwent low pressure metamorphosis of already felsic material. What do we know about the emplacement of the sediments from which they formed ?

I can easily split into several questions, no question.

Comment: I've had some classes on this, but I'm not confident enough to answer... You should have a look at the literature on tonalite-trondhjemite-granodiorite genesis, as they are a major component of Archean cratons. There are several hypothesis on their genesis, like plume underplating or Bédard's delamination: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.gca.2005.11.008

Comment: That was a good hint. Looks like a will have to change my view on this, and future work will bring an answer. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. I also remember that Kerguelen's plateau is considered by some a modern analogue of a continental crust nucleus, a proto-craton if you like. I couldn't find a paper relevant to this, but this one seems to conclude the opposite for Iceland...  https://doi.org/10.1111/j.1365-3121.2008.00839.x

Comment: News that offer a simplified, almost unified approach to generation of early continental crust: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41561-019-0520-6.

Comment: Nice study, thanks for sharing! I still see a little "chicken and egg" issue: they explain how to form TTGs by intracrustal differentiation... which means that to produce continental crust, you need some (mafic) crust in the first place! :D

Comment: Impact melting and weathering as hypothetical contributions to early continental crust ? https://researchportal.port.ac.uk/portal/files/1357984/Cupelli_Geology2014_PP.pdf

Comment: You will soon have enough material to write a nice self answer! :)

Comment: @a_donda New study about Kerguelen showing "strong similarities" in magma emplacement at oceanic and continental crusts: https://doi.org/10.1111/ter.12471